# Adição de colunas em arquivo csv - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, ciência-de-dados

Não estou conseguindo criar um arquivo csv com uma nova coluna(mês). Quando eu tento criar a coluna inteira fica apenas com o mês de dezembro(12) mas a coluna mês deveria corresponder ao número inteiro do mês. Enfim, segue o código:

```
import pandas as pd

dfdados = pd.read_csv('DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep =';')

x = 0

while x <= 1096:
    linha = dfdados.iloc[x]
    data = linha ['Data']
    dia_mes_ano = data.split('/')
    print(dia_mes_ano)
    x = x + 1
    

dfdados['Mês'] = dia_mes_ano[1]

dfdados.to_csv('Dadoss.csv',sep = ';',index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está com dois problemas:
Primeiro o seu problema está acontecendo porque sua variável dia_mes_ano só vai armazenar o último valor do loop, isso faz com que todos os seus meses sejam iguais.
Segundo o pandas é uma ferramenta eficente para trabalhar planilhas muito grandes. Se você fizer um loop que percorre toda a planilha você vai fazer isso de forma menos eficiente do que o pandas é capaz de fazer.
Veja uma forma muito mais eficiente de usar as funcionalidades do pandas para obter os meses sem precisar varrer a planilha:

```
dfdados = pd.read_csv('DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep =';')

meses = dfdados.Data.str.split('/').str[1]
dfdados['Mês']=meses
```

perceba que o comando `meses = dfdados.Data.str.split('/').str[1]` faz exatamente a mesma coisa que você queria: um split do mês e a seleção do elemento na posição 1 da lista. A diferença é que ele faz isso em todos os elementos da coluna Data de uma única vez

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Criando a coluna mês:

```
dfdados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfdados['Data']).month
```

Salvando o csv:

```
dfdados.to_csv('./novo.csv',sep = ';', index = False)
```

Mais sobre o [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

---

Código completo:

```
import pandas as pd

dfdados = pd.read_csv('DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep =';')
dfdados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfdados['Data']).month
dfdados.to_csv('./novo.csv',sep = ';', index = False)
```

---

- Caso o dia apareça primeiro você pode setar dayfirst = True
- Caso o ano apareça primeiro você pode seta yearfisrt = True

Exemplo:

```
dfdados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfdados['Data'], yearfirst = True).month
```

Comment: Seu código erra se você não especificar o formato da data. Pelo menos no meu computador ele assumiu mês/dia/ano e por isso teria que usar `.day` no lugar de `.month`

Comment: sim, mas no caso do exemplo, o mês vai estar no elemento 1 independente de como o seu sistema estiver definido. Na sua solução poderia usar dayfirst=True

Comment: Obrigada! Ajudou muito. Se nao for incomodo pode dar uma olhada na minha outra duvida? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481747/212837

Comment: Gabriela, bom dia! Que bom que resolveu! Caso a resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, considere em marcar a resposta como válida(não é obrigatório mas é uma boa prática para futuros usuários com o mesmo problema). [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg). Visitei a outra pergunta e deixei uma sugestão para resolver o problema. Abraços!